# How do I to get the canonicalized min/max values in jQuery UI's datepicker's beforeShow method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a pair of datepicker objects that I would like to act as a range, so that setting a value in the "low" one adjusts the minDate (and yearRange) in the other and similarly with the "maxDate" in the other one.  The problem is the type of what I get seems like it can be a date or a string or a number or ??? so I am having trouble using it to set the other values.  Code snippet below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( '#from' ).datepicker({          /* the "low" datepicker */
    showOn:         'button',
    changeMonth:        true,
    changeYear:     true,
    defaultDate:        null,
    minDate:        new Date(2009,0,1),
    maxDate:        null,
    buttonImageOnly:    true,
    buttonImage:        '/img/calendar_icon_20x20.png',
    buttonText:     'select date from calendar',
    dateFormat:     'dd-M-yy',
    beforeShow:
        function ( inp, inst ) {
            var v;
            var o = {};
            var miny = new Date(inst.settings.minDate).getFullYear();
            var maxy = new Date(inst.settings.maxDate).getFullYear();

            v = $( '#thru' ).val();  /* the "high" datepicker */
            if (v == '') {
                v = $( '#thru' ).datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
            }
            if (typeof v == 'object') {
                o.maxDate = v;
            } else {
                o.maxDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-M-yy', v.trim());
            }
            maxy = o.maxDate.getFullYear();
            o.yearRange = miny + ':' + maxy;
            return o;
        }
    });
});
```

And I figure I'm going to need to add an `if (typeof v == 'number') {..}` section and try to compute a date from a numerical days offset, and then I still have to worry that if I get a string that it doesn't match up with the dateFormat so the parse will fail.   I assume that there is something in the datepicker code which is already having to do this canonicalization of inputs for default/min/maxDate (presumably into a Date object) isn't there some way for me to access the already canonicalized value (rather than reinventing the wheel badly as I've been doing thus far)?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/). It is pretty good at parsing dates.

Comment: very hard to follow all this description and narrow it down to what your actual problem is but seems like you are missing concept of interacting with the datepicker api on `$( '#thru' )` instead of trying to parse the element value

Comment: I guess the first question is:  I assume that there is something in the datepicker code which is already having to do this canonicalization of inputs for default/min/maxDate (presumably into a Date object) -- isn't there some way for me to access the already canonicalized value ...

Comment: That is, what is returned by `v = $( '#thru' ).datepicker('option', 'maxDate');` seems to be the raw value of whatever was put after 'maxDate:' which can take a great many forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I grabbed the un-minified jquery-ui source and scrounged through it and as near as I can tell it **doesn't** seem to keep the canonicalized dates any place, it recomputes them each time it needs them.  It seems there is a "private" function, `_determineDate`, which you can access to do this canonicalizing, but that's obviously not very future-proof.  Anyway for completeness, here it is:

```
var rawvalue = $( '#other' ).datepicker('option', 'minDate');
var asDate = $.datepicker._determineDate(inst, rawvalue, null);
```